# understanding SHA 256

Tags: python, hash, sha256

```
import hashlib
previous_proof = 0
new_proof = 0
check_proof = False

while check_proof is False:
  hash_operation = hashlib.sha256(str(new_proof**2 - previous_proof**2).encode()).hexdigest()
  if hash_operation[:4] == '0000':
      check_proof = True
  else:
    new_proof+=1
print(hash_operation)
print(   new_proof)
```

I made this script for finding a string in sha256 that starts with '0000'.
Could anyone explain me why if i put '000000'instead of '0000' it takes more time to find the string?
It is supposed to take less time because i have more zeros at the beginning,right?

Comment: Rolling a die until you get 3 sixes in a row might take a while.  Rolling a die until you get 6 sixes in a row will usually take a lot longer.

Answer (score 1):

There are *far less* hashes that start with '000000' compared to '0000' as this is a *restriction* of allowed starts.

With/assuming uniform distribution, that is 256 (2^8) times less: *so taking ~256 times as long seems reasonable*.

Consider that for every '0000' 4-character start there are also '000000'-'0000FF' 6-character starts, where only 1 ('00') out of the range of 256 ('00'-'FF') possibilities of characters in positions 5 & 6 match.

```
              Matches 4?   Matches 6?
0000 00       Yes          Yes
0000 01       Yes          No
0000 10       Yes          No
0000 11       Yes          No
(many more)   Yes          No
```

Comment: So the time for calculating a hash that starts for '0000' equals the time for calculating a hash that finishes with '0000',right?

Comment: @Newdude The occurrence of any '0000' should be generally equally as probable in any location - start, back, middle. It can be expected about 1 in every 65k (2^16) hashes at any given location.

Comment: @Newdude So each SHA256 generation has ~61/65k (~0.093%) chance of '0000' occurring *anywhere* in the string.